# Why my laptop battery is discharged so fast with Elementary OS?

Tags: battery

I constantly have problems with my battery because it discharges very fast. This problem only occurs in elementary OS. In Windows 8 the management of the battery is much better. I have already installed the battery management application from the AppCenter, but the battery still has the same problem. My laptop is a Lenovo Z40/70. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend installing TLP which will help conserve battery power.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```

Though if you haven't yet set elementary up to install from PPAs, run the following command first:

```
sudo apt install -y software-properties-common python3-software-properties python-software-properties
```

Comment: Thanks for your timely response. I hope the problem improves with this application.